# Do I really need countQuery in a native @Query for pagination?

Tags: spring-data-jpa, pagination, spring-data

According to the [reference](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#jpa.query-methods.at-query), `countQuery` is required for native queries pagination (at least there is an example with it). But according to my tests (Spring Boot 2.4.5), @Query pagination works without `countQuery` for such queries:

```
public interface ARepository extends JpaRepository<A, Long>{
  @Query(value = "select * from a", nativeQuery = true)
  Page<A> findAllANative(Pageable pageable);

  @Query(value = "select count(a.id) as aCount, category.name as 
        categoryName " +
        "from a " +
        "join category on a.category_id=category.id " +
        "group by category.name",
        nativeQuery = true)
  List<CountView> findACountByCategoryNative(Pageable pageable);
}
```

As you can see, there is no `countQuery` and they work.

Does pagination work only for these specific queries or I can omit `countQuery` in all cases?